# uninstall.php does not appear to trigger when uninstalling my plugin

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

i am new to plugin development in wordpress and i have have this simple test plugin that i am working on. The problem i am having is that the uninstall.php file does not appear to get trigger and as such the database entried i wish to remove remain after the plugin in uninstalled from the WordPress admin.

**Plugin code:**

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Looks like you made a wrong turn there buddy' );

class TestPlugin
{

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_post_type' ) );
    }

    function activate() {
        // generate a CPT in case 'init' fails
        $this->create_post_type();
        // flush rewrite rules
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function deactivate() {
        // flush rewrite rules
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function uninstall() {
        // delete cpt
        // delete all the plugin data from the DB

    }

    function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'acme_product', array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Acme Product' ) );
    }
}

if ( class_exists( 'TestPlugin' ) ) {
    $newTest = new TestPlugin();
}

// Activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $newTest, 'activate' ) );

// Deactivation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $newTest, 'deactivate' ) );
```

**Uninstall.php**

```
/**
 * Trigger this file on plugin uninstall
 *
 * @package TestPlugin
 */

if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    die;
}

// Clear database stored data
//$acme_products = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'acme_product', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
//
//foreach ( $acme_products as $acme_product) {
//    wp_delete_post( $acme_product->ID, true );
//}

// Access the database via SQL
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'acme_product'" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts)" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts)" );


echo "UNINSTALL DAMMIT!!";
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tested the SQL query just to make sure it worked in phpMyAdmin, and it works fine.

i.e `"DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'acme_product'"`

Comment: Is the file name `uninstall.php` or `Uninstall.php`? Is it in the same subdirectory as the the main plugin file?

Comment: file name is uninstall.php, all lowercase and is located in the same directory as the main plugin file.

Comment: @J.D. Well it turns out you are the closest to a answer on this thread, in as much as yes i did spell it with a lowercase 'u' but i was missing an 'n'. Did not notice this until Drupalizeme asked me to navigate to the file in the browser. Though you should know :P

Comment: :-D I think we've all probably spent hours debugging typoz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was a silly one i had misspelled "uninstall". The problem resolved it self once this was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the uninstall besides the fact that echo a string(this interpreted us failed) and using hardcode prefix.

Below code have been tested locally with the latest version of WordPress.

```
// Access the database via SQL
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'acme_product'" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts)" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts)" );


// echo "UNINSTALL DAMMIT!!";
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Made the changes to my queries but not the the database entry is not getting removed when plugin is deleted.

Comment: Does the code run until the `// Access the database via SQL
global $wpdb;` ? Can you disable all other plugins and try again?

Comment: Also, you are pressing the DELETE link correct?

Comment: i am using a clean wordpress install (on WAMP) with no other plugins installed. Not even Akizmet/Hello Dolly. And yes, i deactivate first then uninstall. I get the impression the file is not being called at all. That is why i added an echo to see if it would return som value. Is there a way to test if the uninstall.php file is being run?

Comment: Verify this is set `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` on your config file. To see if any error ocurr. Also you may try the `error_log();` to write something to error log :)

Comment: Thank, but i get no errors. Just wish there was a way to know if uninstall.php was being run. If i know it is running upon deletion then i know there is a problem with my code.

Comment: Remove this `if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    die;
}` Now can you navigate to the file and see if this is running?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing but i doubt i would have discovered this if you had not asked me to navigate to the specific file in the browser. I MISS spelled `uninstall.php`, i spelled it `unistall.php`, and i never noticed....

Comment: Well happy to help :)

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers the site still thinks you haven't found your solution and is promoting the question, can you write your own answer below with what was in the last comment? Otherwise new people will start trying to figure this out, which isn't possible as your question spells `uninstall.php` correctly

Answer (score 0):

Both of your hooks are `register_activation_hook()`. In order to hook into plugin's deactivation, you should use `register_deactivation_hook()` instead.

Also, this hook should not be confused with `register_uninstall_hook()`, which is best to be triggered after uninstalling a plugin.

You can read more about Activation/Deactivation hooks in the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/).

Comment: Can't believe i missed that, how ever the changing the hook to `register_deactivation_hook()` did not result in the database entry being removed on deletion of the project. I also tried @Drupalizeme suggestion and changed the prefixes to `{$wpdb->prefix}`. I an pretty sure there is a silly mistake somewhere.